# Operations using min max function And properties

Tags: math, calculation

Let be Max(a,min(b,c),d)
How to determine
x-Max(a,min(b,c),d)
and is
Max{x-a,min(x-b,x-c),x-d} correct ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct.

If you need to change the sign on a max/min function it'll just invert, so negating the function will and negating all of it's inputs will just change it from max to min and vise versa.

imagine it on coordination scale, changing the sign is like inverting every thing around an axis, mirror in other word, so min become max

as for your example:

```
x - Max(a,Min(b,c),d) = Min(x-a,Max(x-b,x-c)x-d)
```

Comment: ok, if the answer is right, and you think it was helpful you can accept it as the right answer. this will help future knowledge seeker to find it. @Abla

Comment: My equations are more complicated but I think it is OK.